# MQTT real time Feed to html page in Node JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, websocket, mqtt

My route mqtt.js contains the following :-

```
client.on('connect', function () {
    client.subscribe('shmindia');
    client.publish('shmindia', new Date());
    console.log("********************** MQTT STARTED *********************");
});

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    // message is Buffer 
    m = message;
    console.log(message);
   // client.end();
});

client.on('close', function () {
    console.log(" disconected");
});

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    /*Render the index.hbs and pass the View Model*/
    var vm = {
        title: 'MQTT',
        message: [new Date(), m]
    }
    console.log(vm.message);
    res.render('mqtt/index', vm);
});

router.get('/getsensordata', function (req, res) {
    var vm = {
    data:m
    };
    res.send(vm);
});

module.exports = router;
```

The index.hbs contains the following code:-

```
<div id='container' style="width:100%; height:400px;">

</div>
<script>
    var chart;
    function requestData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:1998/mqtt/getsensordata',
            success: function (point) {
                var series = chart.series[0],
                  shift = series.data.length > 20;
                chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);
                setTimeout(requestData, 1000);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
                events: {
                    load: requestData
                }
            }
    });
</script>
```

so, in this what happens is, the index file, requests for data and then, some data is retrieved from the server.

what i am expecting is when ever the MQTT client publishes the message, the data should go to the index.hbs

HOW CAN I ACHIEVE THAT ?
EDIT 1: i can use websockets, but i want to hide the link to MQTT server, login details.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. Do you 1) want to use MQTT over Websockets to deliver updates direct to the page (There is no way to hide MQTT server/credentials this way). Or 2) Use MQTT on the server side and push updates to the page via websockets?

Comment: i select 2.
but, i dont want to make ajax calls to node server to check if new data have arrived or not.
is der any way ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use AJAX to get updates, use pure websockets to push updates from the server side to the client when a message is delivered to the server.

Use the [express-ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ws) module on the server side, something like this:

```
var expressWs = require('express-ws')(app); //app = express app 

expressWs.app.ws('/sensordata', function(ws, req){});
var aWss = expressWs.getWss('/sensordata');

client.on('connect', function () {
    client.subscribe('shmindia');
    client.publish('shmindia', new Date());
    console.log("********************** MQTT STARTED *********************");
});


client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    // message is Buffer 
    m = message;
    aWss.clients.forEach(function (client) {
        client.send(m);
    });
    console.log(message);
   // client.end();
});
```

And on the webpage side:

```
<script>
   var ws = new Websocket('ws://localhost:1998/sensordata');
   ws.onmessage = function(message){
     var series = chart.series[0],
     shift = series.data.length > 20;
     chart.series[0].addPoint(message, true, shift);
   } 
</script>
```